# Trying to generate an APK in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, apk

I am using Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0) and I am looking to generate an APK. I have the Android plugin installed with the SDK's needed for this project.
I go to File -> Export and then try to click Export Android Application but it tell me my application has compilation errors to resolve. Yet, Eclipse only tells me I have errors to resolve and not where they are coming from. It gives me the message, "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application."

Comment: Look at the "Problems" view, but note that Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for some years now.

Comment: Export will not generate an apk. Use the Run button.